# Java Applet: Reverse Engineering HTTP Calls

Tags: java, http, ssl, applet, reverse-engineering

Are there any tools or methods for logging the HTTP calls of java applets? Even java applets that use SSL?

I am trying to determine how a java applet works. I only have the jar, not the source code and decompiling has only gotten me so far. The Java applet makes a number of HTTP calls as it runs and I would like to intercept these calls to see what they contain and possibly play with the parameters. Are there any tools that can spy on the HTTP calls of java applets running on your computer? Note that the applet uses SSL, so I don't think a tool like ethereal (which spies on everything at the system level) would work.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: The best I was able to do was to use a JAVA decompiler with Eclipse integration.  Then, I would step through the decompiled code in Eclipse.  Unfortunately, the decompiler is not perfect and the approach has its limits.  I put the project down for now, but I'll be sure to update here if I find something.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) ? You can configure it with certificates so it can handle SSL traffic.